# Filtering array as a column in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- elements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- surname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- othername: string (nullable = true)
```

Having that dataframe structure, I'm trying to filter for elements in which value is greater than X e.g. 0.5. However when I try to filter it:

```
df.where(col('elements.value') > 0.5)
```

it throws

```
cannot resolve '(spark_catalog.default.tempD.`elements`.`value` > 0.5D)' due to data type mismatch:
 differing types in '(spark_catalog.default.tempD.`elements`.`value` > 0.5D)' (array<float> and double).;;
```

I can't figure out how to fix that. Wrapping value with float() e.g. float(0.5) changes nothing.
I bet it is a simple fix, but I'm struggling with it too many hours.

Comment: Could you show the output of `df.printSchema()`? It seems `value` is an array rather than a float.

Comment: @mck added to post message. Hmm in that case, how can I base the condition on elements inside this array?

Comment: what's your spark version?

Comment: @mck spark 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try higher order expressions to filter the array:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr('id', 'filter(elements, x -> x.value > 0.5) filtered')
```

A normal `where` filter doesn't work because it cannot be applied onto an array. Imagine if your array contains two structs, one having value > 0.5 and the other value < 0.5. It's not possible to determine whether that row should be included or not.

If you want to filter the rows where ALL values in the array are > 0.5, you can use

```
df.where('array_min(transform(elements, x -> x.value > 0.5))')
```

the clause is only `True` if every item in the array returns `True`.

Comment: it works but with small issue, it includes rows that have empty array in them

Comment: @Kevin then you can add one more filter like `.where('size(new_column) > 0')`, where `new_column` is the new column name of the array column

Comment: but the new column is named " filter(elements, lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable().value AS DOUBLE) > CAST(0.24 AS DOUBLE)), namedlambdavariable())) ", is there a way for specyfing the name of this second argument in selectExpr?

Comment: @Kevin you can add the alias after the expression - see my edited answer